# R function to remove nodes from a network one by one and outputting the largest connected component

Tags: r, igraph

I need to simulate the influence of removing nodes from a network in igraph in R based on different node attributes.  I've created a function below which creates a matrix based on nodes and their corresponding betweenness centrality, orders this and then should cycle through each node in the matrix remove the node and calculate the size of the largest connected component, printing this output for analysis.

```
testbet<- function(g){
  n<-length(V(g))
  mat<- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=n, 0) #betweenness attack
  mat[,1]<-1:n
  bet<-betweenness(g)
  mat[,2]<-bet
  matri<-mat[order(mat[,2]),]
  g2<-g
  for(i in 1:n){
    v=n+1-i
    g2<-delete.vertices(g2, matri[v,1])
    maxcsize2<-max(clusters(g2)$csize)
    print(maxcsize2)
  }
}
```

When it runs it starts to print the output up to a point and then i get the error message:

```
Error in .Call("R_igraph_delete_vertices", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph,  : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
Called from: .Call("R_igraph_delete_vertices", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph, 
    v) - 1, PACKAGE = "igraph")
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm very much stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is arising because the vertex ids in `g2` are being dynamically regenerated, so even if you remove vertex `41`, the ids get reset to `1:99` and then when you go to remove vertex `100` you get an error. You can get around this by giving your graph vertices a unique name attribute and indexing on that instead.

```
library(igraph)

g <- random.graph.game(100, 0.2)

V(g)$names <- paste0("v", 1:length(V(g))) #assign unique name


  testbet <- function(g){
  n <- length(V(g))
  mat <- matrix(ncol=2,nrow=n, 0)
  mat[,1] <- V(g)$names #add vertex name to matrix
  bet <- betweenness(g)
  mat[,2] <- bet
  matri <- mat[order(mat[,2], decreasing = TRUE),]
  g2 <- g
  clustersizes<-integer(n-1)
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    g2 <- delete.vertices(g2, v=which(V(g2)$names==matri[i,1])) #index by name
    maxcsize2 <- max(clusters(g2)$csize)
    clustersizes[i]<-maxcsize2
    }
  df<-as.data.frame(cbind(matri, c(clustersizes, NA)))
  names(df)<-c("vertex_removed", "betweenness", "maxcsize")
  return(df)
 }

df<-testbet(g)
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, i thought that was the issue just wasn't sure how to get around it.  That works wonderfully thank you very much

Comment: Would there be any way to store the results in a data frame?  Print is fine for one variable as I can export this for further analysis - however would be great if I could use this function to explore multiple aspects such as the average degree, diameter etc. Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: Edited to return a dataframe

Comment: Thank you this helps very much and means I can add a range of evaluative metrics to the dataframe. One think I did notice which has confused me a bit is that the i was anticipating the betweenness centrality to be decreasing as the size of the largest connected component decreases as its meant to be removing nodes in that order. However the dataframe it produces shows that the betweenness centrality fluctuates as the size of the largest connected component decreases. Therefore im not sure whether this is working correctly?

Comment: I've managed to resolve this by adapting the order code to  matri <- mat[order(as.numeric(mat[,2]), decreasing =TRUE ),]

Comment: When I've tried to extrapolate other metrics e.g. the number of clusters in an additional column, unfortunately I get an error message along the lines of 'number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)'.  Any advice on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Michael, are you adding an extra element to the vector before combining to account for the last row not containing a value, e.g. in `c(clustersizes, NA)` ?

Comment: No I hadn't been, I will try and add this to my new elements to see if this helps - I wasn't sure what the NA part was doing but now its clearer!  Thankyou Esther you've been phenomenal help on this issue.  I'm not a coder and I'm having to produce this from scratch so I'm really grateful for your assistance!